# how to write a mgf for $X \sim U[0,1]$ and then to generalise it to an interval $[a,b]$

Tags: probability, integration, definite-integrals, moment-generating-functions

So I will try:

$$M(t)=\int^1_0 e^{tx}dx=\frac{1}{t}\left. \left(e^{tx} \right)\right|^1_0=\frac{e^t}{t}-\frac{1}{t}$$

And for general case where the interval is given as $[a,b]$

It looks obviously wrong, I think it's something to do with the partial integration, maybe I could take the $\frac{1}{b-a}$ out of the integral sign, but then a $x$ would be missing. But if I do so then:

$$M(t)=\frac{1}{b-a} \int^b_ae^{tx}dx=\frac{1}{t(b-a)}\left. \left(e^{tx}  \right)\right|^b_a=\frac{e^{tb}-e^{ta}}{t(b-a)}$$

Also looks wrong, but I don't see, where is my mistake.

Comment: $(b-a)$ is a constant.  Just pull it out and integrate $e^{tx}$ and you should get the solution found on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous)#Moment-generating_function)

Comment: @antkam That's what I got.

Comment: there are no mistakes. just put $b=1$ and $a=0$

Comment: But that's correct.  Why do you say it looks wrong?  You integrate some function of $x$ w.r.t. $x$, so of course the result (the MGF) is no longer a function of $x$.  It is indeed called $M(t)$ and is only a function of $t$.

Answer (score 1):

If $Y\sim\mathrm{Unif}(a,b)$ then $Y\stackrel{\mathrm d}= a+(b-a)X$, so
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[e^{tY}] &= \mathbb E[e^{t(a+(b-a)X)}]\\
&= \mathbb E[e^{at}e^{t(b-a)X}]\\
&= e^{at} \mathbb E[e^{t(b-a)X}]\\
&= e^{at} M(t(b-a))\\
&= e^{at} \frac{e^{t(b-a)}-1}{t(b-a)}\\
&= \frac{e^{bt}-e^{at}}{t(b-a)},
\end{align}
which is the moment-generating function of a $\operatorname{Unif}(a,b)$ random variable.